# What is the Putty equivalent command for Mac OS X?

Tags: ssh, macos, putty

In my Windows system, I was able to create a tunnel by running the command below using Putty:

```
putty.exe -D 12345 -P 8888 localhost
```

I'm not used to Mac yet and I would like to try it out on Mac. Does anyone know the command to achieve same tunneling in Mac OS X or do I have to use a client?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  I don't know putty command line options, so I'm not sure what traffic you're actually trying to forward, and in which direction.

Answer (score 6):

`putty`'s command-line options are (mostly, but not entirely) a clone of those that the `openssh` client uses, so the equivalent of your command line above would just be `ssh -D 12345 -p 8888 localhost`.

Read `man ssh` for the full details of the options.

Well. I don't know why you'd forward ports to localhost, but I'm sure that was just a demo ;)

Comment: Thx James. I will try your answer out. :)) . As to why I would ports to localhost, it is needed for bypassing stubborn firewalls.

Comment: UPDATE: I just tried it but it failed, it appears an attempt was made to connect Host 8888 on port 22 which is wrong. ........................ ssh -D 12345 -P 8888 localhost
ssh: connect to host 8888 port 22: Network is unreachable

Comment: Hah. I missed that. it'll be `-p 8888` rather than `-P 8888` :)

Answer (score 5):

MacOSX provide by default a command-line ssh client, just execute it from a terminal with:

```
$ ssh user@hostname
```

To check that options are the same that you are accustomed with PuTTY, read the ssh man reference with:

```
$ man ssh
```

Answer (score 2):

Mac's ssh syntax (and for most other *nix commands) is not the same as in a Linux box. I think you could try `ssh -D 12345 -p 8888 localhost`, but I don't remember quite well. The best way is `man ssh`.

I usually make a config file (`.ssh/config`) with parameters so that you can simply type `ssh bypassfw` if you want to run that command.

```
Host bypassfw
HostName localhost
Port 8888
DynamicForward 12345
```

Comment: Thx for the suggestion. Just tried it but it failed.

Comment: I forgot "localhost" in the command. I also added a .ssh/config file, the method which I used when I was on Mac. However, did you try `man ssh`?

Comment: Did'nt work out :((

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant or not. But I used this command.

```
ssh -L 8080:192.168.0.12:9991 remote_user@192.168.0.12
```

Basically,

```
ssh -L local_port:remote_ip:remote_port remote_user@remote_ip
```